# Jhipster Heroku deployment errors out

Tags: jhipster

I am using Jhiptser version 4.14.5, heroku version 7.19.3 and yarn 1.12.3

I upgraded my application from hipster 4.9.0 to 4.14.5 and am trying to deploy to heroku using command "jhipster heroku".

However am getting the following error. I have spent all day on this and not getting anywhere. Any help appreciated.

I cleaned and reinstalled node, yarn,jhipster and heroku , still same error.

I have cleaned yarn global cache as well.

Installing Heroku CLI deployment plugin
✖ { Error: Command failed: heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy --force
Installing plugin java... yarn add v1.12.3
Installing plugin java... info No lockfile found.Installing plugin java... [1/4] Resolving packages...Installing plugin java... [2/4] Fetching packages...Installing plugin java... [3/4] Linking dependencies...Installing plugin java... [4/4] Building fresh packages...Installing plugin java... success Saved lockfile.Installing plugin java... success Saved 99 new dependencies.Installing plugin java... info Direct dependenciesInstalling plugin java... info All dependenciesInstalling plugin java... ├─ ansicolors@0.3.2Installing plugin java... ├─ co-wait@0.0.0Installing plugin java... ├─ color-name@1.1.3Installing plugin java... ├─ escape-string-regexp@1.0.5Installing plugin java... ├─ has-flag@3.0.0Installing plugin java... ├─ inherits@2.0.3Installing plugin java... ├─ isarray@1.0.0Installing plugin java... ├─ keyv@3.0.0Installing plugin java... ├─ ms@2.1.1Installing plugin java... ├─ opn@3.0.3Installing plugin java... ├─ pify@3.0.0Installing plugin java... ├─ safe-buffer@5.1.2Installing plugin java... ├─ sort-keys@2.0.0Installing plugin java... ├─ strip-ansi@4.0.0Installing plugin java... ├─ url-parse-lax@3.0.0Installing plugin java... └─ which@1.3.1Installing plugin java... Done in 4.45s.Installing plugin java... installed v3.0.1

Installing plugin --force... yarn add v1.12.3
Installing plugin --force... info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.Installing plugin --force... !

error Missing list of packages to add to your project.

Error: yarn add --force@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:/Users/abhinav/.local/share/heroku/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=/Users/abhinav/Library/Caches/heroku/yarn --check-files --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.forked.on (/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.19.3/libexec/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/lib/yarn.js:31:28)

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
```

killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy --force' }

Comment: what happens when you run `heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy --force`?

Comment: I'm not sure if JHipster 4.x is supported anymore. You might need to upgrade to 5.x

Comment: Yes i did run the command but get similar error ----------------------------------- Error: yarn add --force@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:/Users/Buni/.local/share/heroku/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=/Users/Buni/Library/Caches/heroku/yarn --check-files --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.forked.on (~/.local/share/heroku/client/7.19.3/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/lib/yarn.js:31:28)

Comment: try running `heroku plugins:install java`. But i think you'll need to upgrade to jhipster 5

Comment: Hi, I am also getting the same error, **heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy --force**, where the --force is again considered as a plugin. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue? I am using the JHipster version 5.0.1, and I also tried with 5.7.2. But still, the error is the same.